# Informatica- Run parallel mappings in workflow

Tags: mapping, workflow, informatica

I need to run multiple mappings in parallel in a single workflow. I have around 60 tables and i need them to run in parallel. I would like to know how to modify this workflow to run the mappings in parallel? Can someone point me to sample workflows which can help me complete the workflow.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the diagram in the link should help.
[Sample workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTXca.jpg)